# Left padded text

Tags: c, string, padding

TASK: // target - starting an argument in which to record results
target should be a "source" left supplemented with "fill_char" to length "cnt". If cnt is less than the length of the source, it becomes equal to the target source.
      // Now is moving on right and must to change something but I'm not sure what and how. Can you give me advice. And if you have some different decision please share with me. Thank you :)))!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <batch_util.h>

int lpad(char* target, char* source, char fill_char, int cnt)
{
    int i;
    int source_size = strlen(source);
    for (i = 0; i < source_size; i++)
        target[i] = source[i];
    for (i = source_size; i < cnt; i++)
        target[i] = fill_char;
    target[i] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char source[128];
    char target[128];
    char fill_char;
    int cnt;
    scanf("%s\n", &source);
    scanf("%c\n", &fill_char);
    scanf("%d\n", &cnt);
    lpad(target, source, fill_char, cnt);
    printf("%s\n", target);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you a) Format the code correctly (missing indentation, random backticks / `enter code here`) b) Fix it so that it compiles? (the lpad function doesnt have a closing brace).

Comment: It looks suspiciously like this is supposed to be C, not C++?

Comment: yes, but source,cnt and char must be input from the user my program is working okey but is moving source on right etc. if I write monkey = source and "*" for char and 15 for cnt will look like this monkey***********, the answer must be **********monkey..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you can use standard C string functions instead of loops.

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * lpad( char *target, const char *source, char fill_char, size_t cnt )
{
    size_t source_size = strlen( source );

    if ( source_size < cnt )
    {
        memset( target, fill_char, cnt - source_size );
    }

    strcpy( target + ( source_size < cnt ? cnt - source_size : 0 ), source );

    return target;
}

#define N   16

int main(void) 
{
    char *source= "monkey";
    char target[N];

    puts( lpad( target, source, '*', N - 1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
*********monkey
```

As for your code then the function does not append anything to the left.

Comment: yes, but source,cnt and char must be input from the user
my program is working okey but is moving source on right
etc. if I write monkey = source and "*" for char and 15 for cnt will look like this monkey***********, the answer must be **********monkey.. Thank you